# Input string was not in a correct format C#

Tags: c#

[image]

```
   private void textquantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lowitem = "lowitem";  
        string highitem = "highitem";  

        if (Convert.ToInt32(textquantity.Text) <= 5)   
            texthilow.Text = lowitem;   
        else  
            texthilow.Text = highitem;   

    }
```

i always get an error on

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(textquantity.Text) <= 5)
```

Comment: More info. Runtime error or compile? What is the actual error?

Comment: What is the value of `textquantity.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? And please read [ask] couple of times..

Comment: as is clear from image Text is empty. use `int.TryParse` or check for empty stirng

Answer (score 6):

Please check if your textbox has `empty` value it will not convert to `int`.

As you are getting value in `TextChanged` event so when you `press backspace` and there is `no value` in it, it will throw `exception`.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textquantity.Text))
{
int quantity;
if (int.TryParse(textquantity.Text, out quantity))   
        texthilow.Text = quantity.ToString();   
    else  
        texthilow.Text = quantity.ToString();   
}
```

Also try to use `int.TryParse` because it will not `throw exception` if `string` is not a valid `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `TryParse` instead of `Parse`:

```
  int value;

  if (int.TryParse(textquantity.Text, out value))  
    if (value <= 5)   
      texthilow.Text = lowitem; 
    else  
      texthilow.Text = highitem; 
  else {
    // textquantity.Text contains an invalid value, e.g. "bla-bla-bla"
  }
```